# CICS web services - XML parse error

Tags: mainframe

I am currently working in CICS web services and new to XML/WSDL concepts. I got a WSDL file from middleware team and tried to execute the DFHWS2LS utility to create a COBOL language structure from that WSDL. I am getting the following error and was not able to fix this. And suggestions?

> DFHPI9027E The XML parser has found an error: "XSD: The attribute
> 'minOccurs' is not permitted" at line "1" and column"19,015" in
> document "file:/AIGNDVR/DEVL1/ELC/WSDL/MakeOkToSellServiceSOAP.wsdl".
>
> DFHPI9558E ERRORS have been generated processing file
> "/AIGNDVR/DEVL1/ELC/WSDL/  MakeOkToSellServiceSOAP.wsdl".

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="EBCDIC-CP-US"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="MakeOkToSell" targetNamespace="http://MakeOkToSell/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:impl="http://MakeOkToSell/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl/" >
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://MakeOkToSell/">   
    <xs:element name="MakeOkToSellRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>               
                <xs:element name="RequestSystemName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="RequestSystemGearID" type="xs:int"/>
                <xs:element name="transactionIdentifier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="OkToSellDetails">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="CompanyCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>                             
                            <xs:element name="PolicyNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="UplineID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="SSN" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="NPN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="AgencyCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="First5digitSSNandLastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="RequestType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="AgentPositionID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="PrimaryAgentID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="AgentFirstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="AgentLastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="ApplicationState" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="ProductID" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="ProductType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="ApplicationReceivedDate" type="xs:date"/>
                            <xs:element name="ApplicationSignedDate" type="xs:date"/>
                            <xs:element name="GrossPremium" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="NetPremium" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="AdditionalData" minOccurs="0">                            
                                <xs:complexType>
                                       <xs:sequence>
                                          <xs:element name="Property" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                      <xs:simpleContent>
                                         <xs:extension base="xs:string" minOccurs="1">
                                             <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                                         </xs:extension>
                                      </xs:simpleContent>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                      </xs:element>
                                     </xs:sequence>
                                   </xs:complexType>
                                            </xs:element> 
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MakeOkToSellResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="UID">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="EvaluationStatus">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="TaskID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="ErrorDetails" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ErrorCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ErrorType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ErrorMessage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ObjectType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ObjectID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>                          
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Warnings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="WarningCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="WarningType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="WarningMessage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ObjectType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="ObjectID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>                          
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
       <xs:element name="MakeOkToSellFault">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="errorMessage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="errorCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>  
  <wsdl:message name="MakeOkToSellRequest">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:MakeOkToSellRequest" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>  
      <wsdl:message name="MakeOkToSellResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:MakeOkToSellResponse" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>   
      <wsdl:message name="MakeOkToSellFault">
         <wsdl:part element="impl:MakeOkToSellFault" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
     <wsdl:portType name="MakeOkToSellService">
      <wsdl:operation name="MakeOkToSell">
         <wsdl:input message="impl:MakeOkToSellRequest" name="MakeOkToSellRequest"/>
         <wsdl:output message="impl:MakeOkToSellResponse" name="MakeOkToSellResponse"/>
    <wsdl:fault message="impl:MakeOkToSellFault" name="MakeOkToSellFault"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="MakeOkToSellServiceBinding" type="impl:MakeOkToSellService">
   <wsaw:UsingAddressing wsdl:required="false"/>
      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document"  transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>        
      <wsdl:operation name="MakeOkToSell">
         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="urn:MakeOkToSell"/>
         <wsdl:input name="MakeOkToSellRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body    use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>      
     <wsdl:output name="MakeOkToSellResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body    use="literal"/>enter code here
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="MakeOkToSellService">
      <wsdl:documentation>WSDL File for MakeOkToSell</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:MakeOkToSellServiceBinding" name="MakeOkToSellServiceSOAP">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:9080/MakeOkToSellService" />
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Well, what is at column 19,015 of line one? I suspect what you have shown is not what you have passed to the XML processor, even if it is what you think you've passed.

Comment: Error looks to be on **Property** element which has a minOccurs="1", and no type information (there is a complex type though).

Comment: @BruceMartin I thought that as well, but I'm pretty sure it will get the type from the complex type (I think the bad indentation leads astray to start). I don't think we're looking at the correct source document, so I then gave up.

Answer (score 0):

DFHWS2Ls is presumably being run from JCL on the MF. I note that the WSDL document has an encoding of EBCDIC-CP-US, which makes sense, but that's not the encoding we're viewing it in. I presume that the WSDL has either been pretty-printed here for legibility, or a transcoding error caused everything to flow into one long line in the EBCDIC version.

I've loaded the WSDL up in a WSDL validator (I used the validator in the Eclipse Web Tools project). It reported the same problem, only this time at line 39: <xs:extension base="xs:string" minOccurs="1"> . I'm not sure what the WSDL author was trying to achieve, but that minOccurs is invalid in XML, I'd suggest deleting it.

[edited to correct markup on XML tags]